# How is the expression of variance calculated

Tags: variance

I saw this derivation of the variance formula $\text{Var}(X)=E[X^2]-(E[X])^2$ in the Wikipedia article on [Variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance):

[image: Var(X) = E[(X-E[X])^2]; = E[X^2 - 2X E[X] + (E[X])^2]; = E[X^2] - 2E[X] E[X] + (E[X])^2; = E[X^2] - (E[X])^2.]

I don't understand how to get from step 2 to step 3 (the section with the pink rectangle)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following principles applied:

- Expected value of a sum is sum of expected values $E[Y+Z]=E[Y]+E[Z]$
- Expected value is a constant $E[Y]\in\mathbb{R}$
- Expected value of a constant is that constant $E[c]=c$
- If you multiply a variable by a constant and calculate the expected value, it is the same as if you would calculate the expected value from the multiplied variable, i.e. $cE[Y]=E[cY]$
  $$
  E[X^2 - 2XE[X] + (E[X])^2]$$
  Additivity
  $$= E[X^2] - E[2XE[X]] + E[(E[X])^2]$$ 
  Multiplication by constant
  $$= E[X^2] - 2E[X]E[X] + E[(E[X])^2] 
  $$
  Expected value is a constant, expected value of a constant is the constant
  $$= E[X^2] - 2E[X]E[X] + (E[X])^2 
  $$

Comment: Thanks, "Expected value is a constant, expected value of a constant is the constant" answered my question :)